# Getting API error on video upload and stream but locally its working fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

My code is hosted on cloud run service of GCP, here is the example snippet of the code:

```
// Serve the video from Google Cloud Storage
const bucket = storageClient.bucket(bucketName);
const file = bucket.file(videoName);

const videoSize = file.getMetadata().size;
const range = req.headers.range;
console.log(range, "Range ", videoSize, " videoSize");
const CHUNK_SIZE =10 ** 6; // 1MB
const start = Number(range?.replace(/\D/g, '')) || 0;
const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);
const contentLength = end - start + 1;

const headers = {
    'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    'Content-Length': contentLength,
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
};
```

Please help, if any clue what i am missing.

The error i am getting 502, with response : upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error.

Keep in mind locally its working fine.

Comment: What's the total size of your Video or Picture?

Comment: size ranges from 50 mb to 500 mb max.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload more than 32Mb on Cloud Run (cf [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits)).

The best solution for that is to [generate signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) and redirect the request to this URL to post the content directly to Cloud Storage

The other solution is to use a HTTP/2 compliant server and client. You have no limit with this protocol version.